# File share delivery of SSRS without domain

Tags: reporting-services, workgroup

I am trying to schedule the delivery of a report to a shared folder in a workgroup(without domain). But I keep getting the error message of

> Failure writing file: A logon error occurred when attempting to access the file share. The user account or password is not valid.

I have tried several combinations of acounts with or without ComputerName:

- ShareAccount
- Share\ShareAccount
- Server\ServerAdmin
- Server\ShareAccount

And I have created an identical account with same password on both side.
Also, have tried set and unset unattended execution account with server administrator account.
I am sure the shared folder can be accessed with the same UNC path and account in windows explorer. Not sure what else I can try.

Is there anybody successfully do the file share delivery without domain? Or any other way I can schedule to export a report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature works fine in SSRS so it is your settings which are wrong.

You will also want to have the subscription run as a specified user.
Create a **local user** on the computer to where you wish to save your report. Call it **ReportUser**.
For the purposes of this answer, we will call the the computer where you wish to save the report **FileServer**.

ReportUser needs write access to the share you are trying to use.

Try your report - if it still doesn't work then:

1. Launch Windows Explorer but **[Run As](https://superuser.com/questions/290940/how-to-launch-windows-explorer-with-the-privileges-of-a-different-domain-user)** your new ReportUser - you will need to enter the password you have just created.
2. Navigate to the share by typing \\computername\fileshare - this proves your share is setup correctly.
3. Right click in the folder and create a new text document. this proves you have write permission to the folder.

Successfully completing those steps will mean that SSRS will be able to write to the share.

Within SSRS you need to be writing to:

> \\computername\fileshare

The username will be **\FileServer\ReportUser** with a password that you have just created.

One more thing - run the schedule straight after your test - to prove something isn't happening to the network, e.g. overnight maintenance etc.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I am confused, how to create "Windows Domain User" without domain(AD server).

Comment: Ha! Fair point! You need to create a user on the file share PC that the SSRS can use. So it would be fileserverPC\ReportUser.

Comment: When used identical account (with same user name and password), I got another error message "Access to the path xxx is denied", and I had confirmed that login with the account can create a new text file to the share folder. And I have also tested SERVER\ReportUser, SHARE\ReportUser and ReportUser only. Frustrated...

Comment: Identical account? You need to use the **same** account. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you!! Finally, I got it work!! Your solution is correct, to set both ReportServer and FileServer with same account and set the username with FileServer\ReportUser. Actually, I tried this combination before, but it not work. Today, I created a new folder and it works. The problem is I already had tested the writing permission of the original folder by the ReportUser account before, and seems no difference with the new one. I still trying to figure out the root cause of the failure, maybe is about samba.

Answer (score 0):

Environment: All machines are Windows Server. SSRS SQL Server 2016 version on one machine (SSRS service is the sole process running there). SSRS catalog on another machine that hosts SQL Server 2016. File delivery to a third machine.

On the SSRS machine (the one hosting the Reporting Services service), create a local account.

On the receiving machine (the one where the file will be delivered), create a local account with the same name and password as above. Also on the receiving machine, share a directory and grant read/write permissions to the local account just created.

On the Subscription tab of the Report Manager interface (or whatever is used to create a subscription), for the "Credentials used to access the file share" setting, select "Use the following Windows user credentials". Enter the name of the account created above, but do not prefix it with anything ("FILESERVER\ShareDeliveryUser" bad; "ShareDeliveryUser" good). Enter the password.

I tried numerous combinations, including attempting to use the "file share account," but this was the only way that worked.

Strangely, on the Report Manager interface, the "Result" of the last run always shows "Failure writing file...", although the file is indeed delivered.

Attributing original answer to post by user ExoStatic here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdc5b51c-444b-442d-9657-3cf5495e79d0/file-share-delivery-failing#7725882e-d7c6-4b3d-88f6-2620409c3d48. Edited for clarity.